# bindService is not calling the onCreate method of my Service Class

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to bind a service to my activity and some reason after this piece of code is executed:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        httpdIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HttpdService.class);
            bindService(httpdIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }).start();
```

Nothing else happens. There is no exception, but the onCreate method isn't called like it is supposed to. I might be misunderstanding how this works but I thought after this thread was run the service should be created right after. Is this not correct? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you declare your service in the manifest?

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This was definitely the issue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the service binds, it will call the `onBind()` method of the service, and not `onCreate()`. Check out this image which shows the lifecycle of a bound service (taken from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Lifecycle)):

[image]

Indeed, the only way to call the `onCreate` method of the service is to call it using the `startService()` method. According to the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle):

> If someone calls Context.startService() then the system will retrieve
>   the service (creating it and calling its onCreate() method if needed)
>   and then call its onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method with the
>   arguments supplied by the client.

---

In any case, if you want the `onCreate()` service to be called, you just have to start the service before binding to it:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(startIntent);
bindService(startIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer but it turns out I had to just add it into my manifest.

Comment: How can this be assumed as an answer ? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Not sure if this is correct... the documentation for the BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag says

"Flag for bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int): automatically create the service as long as the binding exists. Note that while this will create the service, its onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method will still only be called due to an explicit call to startService(Intent). Even without that, though, this still provides you with access to the service object while the service is created."

By service being created, onCreate() should be getting called.

Comment: I don't think this is right, If service is not currently running (for any fresh start), services onCreate() method will be called regardless of on what mode you are starting the service (background service / bind service with BIND_AUTO_CREATE).

only onStartCommand() and onBind() calls has effects. i.e. during startService() -- onStartCommand() will be called (not onBind) and during bindService() -- onBind() will be called (not onStartCommand())